Why image isn't shrinking according to it's parent's width and height
I have wrapped a img tag with a div tag.
<div className="product-details-container">
        <div className="product-img-wrapper">
            <ListingCardImage imgAlt={product.title} imgSrc={product.image}/>
        </div>
</div>

And I've given width and height properties to product-img-wrapper. But the image size isn't adjusted to screen view.
css
.product-details-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-img-wrapper {
  max-width: 60vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.product-img-wrapper img{
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

The image rendered size is 555x617px and the div.product-img-wrapper is 616.8x364.8. I want understand why the img is not shrinked and whether it's the right way to write a img wrapper?
ListingCardImage code
return <>
        <img src="https://fakestoreapi.com/img/81fPKd-2AYL._AC_SL1500_.jpg" alt={imgAlt} />
    </>



please post a [repro] with a parsed example not your React markup.

Generally speaking, especially for responsive purposes, your img should be 100% of its parent to fill the width.
If you need gaps you can use padding or margin.


.product-details-container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.product-img-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid red;
  max-width: 60vw;
  max-height: 50vh;
}

.product-img-wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
<div class="product-details-container">
  <div class="product-img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/556/617">
  </div>
</div>




No, it's not happening. I have given mostly as you mentioned. The image is coming out from it's wrapper. I have edited and added SS.

as of now I have given values as
`.product-img-wrapper {
max-width: 300px;
max-height: 300px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
.img-shell {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}`
`const ListingCardImage: React.FC = ({
imgSrc, imgAlt
}) => {
return <>
    <img className="img-shell" src={imgSrc} alt={imgAlt} />
</>

} 

`
